# Identification of this control panel for a four-engine plane

Tags: flight-controls, aircraft-identification, flight-instruments, cockpit

While cataloguing a printer's copper plates I came across a control panel image, and I have attached it here in the hope someone can identify what plane it's from. The [Lorenz blind-landing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_beam) instrument gives an indication of the period.

[image: Image showing four lever engine controls, dials, etc.]

Comment: copper plates!  wonderful!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is almost definitely the cockpit of a Short Stirling of unknown mark, a 4-engine British heavy bomber from World War II.

The [RAF Museum's website has an (admittedly low-resolution) photo](https://www.rafmuseum.org.uk/research/archive-exhibitions/worth-a-thousand-words-air-diagrams/pilots-controls-stirling-i.aspx) that matches quite closely, as does [this history website](https://218squadron.wordpress.com/british-allied-bombs-lac-dignum-note-book/). Here's my thought process:

1. the placards (not just the photo's labels) are in english, so it's likely either Commonwealth or American-built
2. the Stirling power quadrant is a match (2 levels of 4 levers each; it's a 4-engine bomber)
3. engine instruments directly above throttles
4. the engines have boost gauges; the Bristol Hercules engine of the Stirling was supercharged
5. odd-shaped cutout on the right side (just above the marked Air Speed Indicator in your photo)
6. my second link has a photo with a matching `CAUTION JETTISON CONTAINERS BEFORE BOMBS` placard on the right side
7. the Lorenz system was used in British (and German) aircraft during WW2, but I can't seem to find any US bombers that used it.
8. it has a retractable undercarriage; Short's Sunderland flying boat [has a lot of the panel in common](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/61/92/a4/6192a4da072c41bf631100e6cc013a1b.jpg), but it was wider and didn't have the goofy notch on the right side, and it obviously had no landing gear.

In short, I'm pretty confident this is a Stirling.

Other aircraft I looked up and discarded as not a match:

- Avro Lancaster
- Avro Shackleton
- Boeing B-17
- Consolidated B-24
- Handley-Page Halifax
- Short Sunderland
- Avro Vulcan (similar throttle quadrant, otherwise way off)

Comment: *jettison containers before bombs*. Containers of what?

Comment: @Mazura yeah, good question. I'm guessing incendiaries — the British used ["Small Bomb Containers" (SBCs)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:British_SBC_WWII_IWM_CH_6272.jpg) to load and drop 4lb or 30lb incendiary devices. Also possible: Wikipedia has a cited statement that "Up to six ferry tanks could also be installed within the wing bomb cells in order to increase fuel capacity by a further 220 gallons" but I'm not sure they'd label that this way.

Comment: See also the wikipedia article on the [Avro Lancaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Lancaster#Bombs) which talks about the incendiary loads / SBCs.

Comment: Thanks for that